# Can only delete 100 records on SharePoint list using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, adodb

I have a VBA that upload/edit/delete items on a SharePoint list using ADODB.

Everything worked fine for months until June 1, 2023. Now I can only upload/edit but cannot delete more than 100 records on a SharePoint list.

When I run my procedure, 100 records are deleted and then the procedure stops and I get "Cannot update. database or object is read-only" error. I'm sure that I have right permissions in this list.

The error occurs in the cnt.Execute line

```
...

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

...

cnt.Execute mySQL, , adCmdText

...
```

Where mySQL is a query that deletes everything from a list "DELETE * FROM [MY_LIST]"

It's weird that 100 items are deleted before the error

I thought about pagination issues but this doesn't make much sense using VBA I guess. I already tried using a different list, a new SharePoint or exploring SharePoint configurations, but couldn't find the problem.